# Prisma Satellite Data Projection Problem when exporting as .tiff in Python

Tags: python, projection, prisma

I have Prisma Hyperspectral data. However I don't have software to open .he5. That's why I try to convert the data via Python.
First of all, I share screenshots about data.

[First page of Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC3vf.png) [Second page of Metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2C6Se.png) [Lat Lon from metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvJHn.png) [My WGS84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuyVK.png) [ENVI UTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mzgke.png) [ArcGIS UTM to WGS84](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gn0qp.png) [Data dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kCYg.png)

So, My problem is imaging shift (approx. 500m eastwest) on my data (image 4) and ENVI data (image 5 and 7.) I put Image 6 to show that when I convert the data from UTM to WGS84 via ArcGIS, it resample and change dimensions of x and y. Code is:

```
import h5py
import numpy as np
import rasterio
from osgeo import gdal

input_file='D:\Prisma\PRS_L2D_STD_20200506085209_20200506085213_0001.he5'
f = h5py.File(input_file, 'r')

dataset0 = f.get('HDFEOS')
dataset1 = dataset0.get('SWATHS')
dataset2 = dataset1.get('PRS_L2D_HCO')
dataset3 = dataset2.get('Data Fields')
dataset4 = dataset2.get('Geolocation Fields')
latitude = dataset4.get('Latitude')
longitude= dataset4.get('Longitude')
s_cube = dataset3.get('SWIR_Cube')
v_cube = dataset3.get('VNIR_Cube')

swir = np.array(s_cube)
vnir = np.array(v_cube)
lat = np.array(latitude) 
lon = np.array(longitude) 

dim=swir.shape
sim=vnir.shape
a=dim[0]
b=dim[2]
c=dim[1]+sim[1]
stacked=np.empty([a,b,c])

i=0
l=0
while i < dim[1]:
    stacked[:,:,(238-i)]=swir[:,i,:]
    i=i+1
while i < c:
    stacked[:,:,(238-i)]=vnir[:,l,:]
    i=i+1
    l=l+1
stacked = stacked.astype(np.uint16)
stacked_reshaped = np.transpose(stacked, (2, 0, 1))

with rasterio.open( 'deneme.tiff','w',
                   height=a,
                   width=b,
                   count=c,
                   dtype=stacked_reshaped.dtype,
                   ) as dst:
        dst.write(stacked_reshaped)

koordinatsız_tif='C:\\Users\gultekin.erten\Desktop\deneme.tiff'
koordinatlı_tif="C:\\Users\gultekin.erten\Desktop\deneme_son.tiff"
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
eski_tiff = gdal.Open(koordinatsız_tif)
dtype = gdal.GDT_UInt16
projection = """GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]"""
bottom_left_y = np.amax(lat)
z=np.amax(lat)-np.amin(lat)
pixel_y_size = z/a
bottom_left_x = np.amin(lon)
p=np.amax(lon)-np.amin(lon)
pixel_x_size = p/b
yeni_tiff = driver.Create(koordinatlı_tif, eski_tiff.RasterXSize,eski_tiff.RasterYSize, 239, dtype)
geotransform = (bottom_left_x, pixel_x_size, 0.0, bottom_left_y,0.0, -pixel_y_size)
yeni_tiff.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
yeni_tiff.SetProjection(projection)

for j in range(c):
    x=eski_tiff.RasterXSize
    y=eski_tiff.RasterYSize
    array = eski_tiff.GetRasterBand(j+1).ReadAsArray(0,0,x,y)
    yeni_tiff.GetRasterBand(j+1).WriteArray(array)
    yeni_tiff.FlushCache()
```